# Basic Authentication using database

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm using Basic Authentication and I need to check the credentials through the database instead.

I'm working on a `.net` `mvc` project that I've not developed by my own and I'm not aware how the password is being hashed.

Can you help me please?

My Basic Athentication filter is the following:

```
using EMSMVC.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;

namespace EMSMVC.Filters
{
    public class BasicAuthenticationAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            var authHeader = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization;

            if (authHeader != null)
            {
                var authenticationToken = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter;
                var decodedAuthenticationToken = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(authenticationToken));
                var usernamePasswordArray = decodedAuthenticationToken.Split(':');
                var userName = usernamePasswordArray[0];
                var password = usernamePasswordArray[1];

                //Check with database instead
                var isValid = userName == "test" && password == "password";

                EMSMVCEntities entities = new EMSMVCEntities();


                if (isValid)
                {
                    var principal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(userName), null);
                    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;

                    return;
                }

            }

            HandleUnathorized(actionContext);
        }

        private static void HandleUnathorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
            actionContext.Response.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic Scheme='Data' location = 'http://localhost:");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using basic authentication when you could use the login systems built into asp.net?

Comment: @ADyson I need it for web api because we need some users to login can access some endpoints from a tablet device using a mobile app.

Comment: That doesn't require basic auth. There are more modern and sophisticated ways which are supported out of the box. Research asp.net identity. And if you want an API, use Web API instead of MVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I replaced this code:

```
            //Check with database instead
            var isValid = userName == "test" && password == "password";

            EMSMVCEntities entities = new EMSMVCEntities();

            if (isValid)
```

with this one:

```
            EMSMVCEntities entities = new EMSMVCEntities();
            entities.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

            var myUser = entities.AspNetUsers.Where(e => e.Email == userName).Select(c => new { c.PasswordHash }).FirstOrDefault();   

            var hasher = new PasswordHasher();
            var hashResult = hasher.VerifyHashedPassword(myUser.PasswordHash, password);

            if (hashResult == PasswordVerificationResult.Success)
```